# Why does MMA fail to find a solution but WA does?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities, wolfram-alpha-queries

I am looking for $n$, where

$$\dfrac{2^{-3 n-2} \pi ^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}<\dfrac{1}{10000000000000000}$$

We can just test values of $n$ and find the smallest $n = 13$, or any $n \gt 13$ or can use various other approaches/commands to fnd this result.

When I try

```
 Reduce[152587890625*2^(14 + 3*n)*Pi^(1 + n)*(1 + n)! < 64^n*(1 + n)!^2, n, Integers]
```

Mathematica fails to find an answer.

However, when I direct the call to WA, I get [image]

Why is Reduce not finding this using MMA, V13.0.1, x86, Windows 10, but WA shows the result?

Comment: `NSolve[{(2^(-3 n - 2) Pi^(n + 1)/(n + 1)!) == 10^-16, n > 0}, n][[1]] /. r_Real :> Ceiling[r]`

Comment: @BobHanlon: As I mention in the opening, there are many ways to find this. My question is why reduce works in WA, but nor in MMA. Thannks.

Comment: is it possible WA is using an updated version of the kernel or code which is not yet released?

Comment: @Nasser: Such details are hidden, so anything is possible. But other methods can find the result, so that would be odd.

Comment: `Reduce` works the same as `NSolve`, i.e., `Reduce[{(2^(-3 n - 2) Pi^(n + 1)/(n + 1)!) == 10^-16, n > 0}, n] /. r_Root :> Ceiling[r]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, my stab at W|A gave a different output than the OP (something like what I show for `Reduce` below, in fact).

Second, I'm not sure how to read the W|A output the OP shows.  For instance `n = 13` is not the solution to the inequality, just one number that satisfies it.  `Reduce` would not (and should not!) produce that output.  Possibly W|A has a multipronged, time-constrained approach, one of which methods is direct search.  Enough speculation, though.

Third, we can get `Reduce` to produce some of the solution set:

```
Reduce[
 152587890625*2^(14 + 3*n)*Pi^(1 + n)*(1 + n)! < 64^n*(1 + n)!^2 &&
  0 < n < 200, n, Integers]
(*  n == 13 || n == 14 || ... || n == 199  *)
```

Another approach would be to use `FindInstance`, but it's still not the same as W|A:

```
FindInstance[
 152587890625*2^(14 + 3*n)*Pi^(1 + n)*(1 + n)! < 64^n*(1 + n)!^2,
 n, Integers]
(*  {{n -> 198}}  *)
```

Comment: good answer. I think WA uses AI also. May be that is what it did to solve this.  AI is now used in lots of places in math.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Interesting, I tried using the exact same syntax in both places, which has never failed me before until now. I also agree that the way WA gave results s quite odd. Thanks